# Docker run -v : Unable to mount a bind volume : "invalid volume specification"

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm quite new to Docker. I'm running on **Windows 10 Enterprise** and am trying to containerize an existing app that runs on windows (so it's a **Windows container**). I don't know if this matters but the container is rather large (8 GB).
I need to share a config file (that lives on the host) with the container that the app will use when starting. I was thinking that a **bind volume** was simplest.

**Problem:** On running the image I get *docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '<source path>:<target path>'*

Container was built with this command:
`docker build -t my_image .`
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT .\application.exe ..\Resources
```

**Here is what I've tried**
`docker run -it -v c:/Users/my_user:/app my_image`

I've tried every combination of C:/, C:\, C:\\, /c/, //c/, \c\, \\c\, etc.

I've tried multiple combinations of /app, //app, \app, \app, C:\app, etc.

I've also tried with and without :rw appended to the end

I've tried the ```--mount``` syntax which consistently outputs: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '/app'. (tried a bunch of variations of /app here too)

I've tried every possible combination (except the right one). **Please help!**

Comment: If the provided answer helped in solving your problem, please mark the question as solved by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using a Windows container, your file path will change. Try the below command, from the docs [Persistent Storage in Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/persistent-storage#bind-mounts)

```
docker run -it -v c:\Users\my_user:c:\app my_image
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a powershell and trying to run docker using `docker run` command you can try this approach. It worked for me in windows powershell (vs code powershell)

```
docker run -v ${pwd}\src:/app/src -d -p 3000:3000 --name react-app-c2  react-app-image
```

Here react-app-c2 is container name and react-app-image is image name
-v is for volume and ${pwd} is for current working directory
/app/src is for the containerdirectory.